# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "488.15 EUR"

Tags: java, exception, automation, assert, parseint

I make automation testing and I want extract text from  id element( ok I make it using comand getText() is works, text is "488.15 EUR",after I  want make operation with this nr ,I want to subtract 2 from this number that I received:488-2
It is my code :

```
int suma = Integer.parseInt(Suma.getText());
            
int rest = suma- 2;
Assert.assertTrue(Suma.getText().equals(rest));
```

But I have next error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "488.15 EUR"
please help me fix this error.Thank you.

Comment: What number would you expect `488.15 EUR` to be?  Is `Catea` a number as well?

Comment: I need only number:488.15

Comment: a) so get rid of non-numeric chars b) since when is `488.15` an integer?

Comment: Variable names begin [lower case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off. "488.15 EUR" is a String, which cannot be parsed to any number, because it doesn't purely consist of numbers.

Secondly, you'll lose those .15 at the end if you try to convert it to an int. Use double instead. it preserves those values.

Remove the last three characters, to make suma.getText() only consist of numbers

```
String sumaOnlyNum = suma.getText().substring(0, suma.getText().length() - 4);
```

Convert it to double instead of int

```
double suma = Double.parseDouble(sumaOnlyNum);
```

Comment: this code works.Thank you very much

Comment: Note that if you'll ever use any currency, which might be longer/shorter than "EUR", you're gonna run into a problem. And also; generally try/catch any parsing operations you're not 100% sure they're gonna work

Comment: @Z-100 Three-letter currency abbreviations are governed by an ISO standard, ISO 4217. They are guaranteed to be three letters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oh, really? Didn't know that. Thank you! :D (In that case ignore my comment above).